# How to remove EventListener in anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `removeEventListener` but in line with          `event.target.removeEventListener('click', myName, false);` is mistake. I tried different ways but none works.

```
document.querySelector('#imagesContainer').addEventListener('click', function myName (event) {

    var images = this.formData.getAll('images[]');

    var picName = event.target.parentNode.dataset.name;

    var id = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
    var xxx = document.getElementById(id);
    xxx.outerHTML = "";

    delete xxx;

    for (var n = 0; n < images.length; n++) {
        if (images[n].name == picName) {
            var removedObject = images.splice(n, 1);
            removedObject = null;
            break;
        }
    }

    this.formData.delete('images[]');
    [].forEach.call(images, function(image){
        this.formData.append('images[]', image);
    }.bind(this));

    event.target.removeEventListener('click', myName, false);

}.bind(this), false);
```

Comment: because you `.bind(this)` on `function myName` - bind creates a new function, so the function that is passed to click handler isn't `myName`, it's the myName bound to `this` - but you can't simply add `.bind(this)` to the remove code, because that would be a different myName bound to this

Comment: So how to call to myName function ?

Comment: BTW, `delete xxx;` won't actually do anything. See [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), where it says "*The **delete** operator removes a given property from an object.*" and "*Unlike what common belief suggests, the delete operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory.*"

Comment: in fact, in strict mode it would be an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you `.bind(this)` on `function myName` - bind creates a new function, so the function that is passed to click handler isn't `myName`, it's the myName bound to `this` - but you can't simply add `.bind(this)` to the remove code, because that would be a different myName bound to this

One solution is to use an IIFE to "capture" `this` as `_this`, then use `_this` instead of `this` in your code: e.g.

```
document.querySelector('#imagesContainer').addEventListener('click', (function(_this) {
    return function myName (event) {
        // replace this with _this
        var images = _this.formData.getAll('images[]');
        var picName = event.target.parentNode.dataset.name;

        var id = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
        var xxx = document.getElementById(id);
        xxx.outerHTML = "";

        delete xxx;

        for (var n = 0; n < images.length; n++) {
            if (images[n].name == picName) {
                var removedObject = images.splice(n, 1);
                removedObject = null;
                break;
            }
        }

        _this.formData.delete('images[]');
        [].forEach.call(images, function(image){
            _this.formData.append('images[]', image);
        }.bind(_this));

        // here you can use this, because this will be the element that fired the click event
        this.removeEventListener('click', myName, false);
    };
}(this)), false);
```

Comment: Not working properly. I am usint this listener to removing pictures which are moved using drag & drop to droping area and now is working only for one picture but if there is many pictures stops working for rest of them. When I drag & drop another pistures to droping area again works only for one.

Comment: well you remove the event listener after the first click - do you add the listener again? is there any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't add listener later, where should be located removeEvent Listener ? If I add two times and remove one in console is: TypeError: xxx is null

Comment: `I don't add listener later` I provided code based on your code and the question - I have no idea when your code should remove the listener, I also have no idea what you are doing in the console, so I can't help there either. Seems one problem is that you haven't figured out the desired behaviour of your code

Comment: You have probably right. I have to rethink my code but your solution for removing listener is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you save a reference to the bound function first you can remove it that way.

```js
const fooBound = foo.bind({hello: 'world'});
btn.addEventListener('click', fooBound);
function foo(event) {
 console.log(this);
 btn.removeEventListener('click', fooBound);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">clicker</button>
```